# Detect Visual Studio Compile (for C++ file, not build) Begin and End event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In my C# Visual Studio Extension, I am trying to detect the **beginning** and the **end** of the Visual Studio Compile (for a C++ file) command. Unfortunately, no luck so far.

I want to execute some custom actions on these two events. I successfully detected the Build command but I didn't found anything about the Compile. This is why I do not have any code to show you, I wasn't able to find any topic related to this problem.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use pre/post build events for the project?

Comment: What custom actions are you looking to run? Perhaps there is a better way to address this using custom msbuild targets?

Comment: I am trying to execute some code analysis only when a Compile event successfully executed on a C++ file. To execute this stuff on Build event it will not be a good idea from the usability perspective. My actions are only **Compile related**.

Comment: Please try to use [ProjectBuildStarted event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcprojectengineeventsclass.projectbuildstarted?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and [ProjectBuildFinished](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcprojectengineeventsclass.projectbuildfinished?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) event.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT is there any way to use these to detect the compile events and not build events? MSDN does not have much info about them